# SQL Query how to get rows that are in range of AM time and PM time with Current Date

Tags: sql

So i have this table of reports:

| report_Id | report_date |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022-12-07 08:00:00 |
| 02 | 2022-12-07 12:00:00 |
| 03 | 2022-12-07 22:00:00 |

What I wanted to do is to get rows that are reported in 05:00:00 between 12:00:00 which I would like to name as AM and rows that are reported in 13:00:00 between 23:00:00 as PM.

This would be the output example for AM:

| report_Id | report_date |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022-12-07 08:00:00 |
| 02 | 2022-12-07 12:00:00 |

And this would be the output example for PM:

| report_Id | report_date |
| --- | --- |
| 03 | 2022-12-07 22:00:00 |

Did try to search but it would be really helpful if I can get answers from here. Thank You

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS?

Comment: Can you share us on what you've tried?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to extract the time from a datetime in your DBMS? What DBMS are you using? Have you looked up its docs to find such function?

Comment: Date/time functionality is often product specific. I.e. you really need to specify which dbms you're using.

Answer (score 7):

Postgres variant:
You can use `CASE` for creating new column for example to mark AM and PM as following using CTE, where you can filter rows by new column:

```
With t1 as(
select 
report_id, 
report_date,
case when report_date::time between '05:00:00'::time and '12:00:00'::time then 'AM' else 'PM' end as time_of_day
from table) 
Select * from t1 where time_of_day = 'AM'
```

Comment: If you do `cast(report_date as time)` instead, your query will be ANSI/ISO compliant - and work on several products (incl. Postgresql.)

Comment: @jarlh That's true, there are several ways to do it, but the way I did it just for visual clarification for starters as I see it as syntax sugar

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL ::

FOR AM :

select * from table where report_date between '2022-12-07 00:00:00' and '2022-12-07 11:59:59'

FOR PM:

select * from table where report_date between '2022-12-07 12:00:00' and '2022-12-07 23:59:59'

Comment: Unfortunately, these queries will be completely useless tomorrow or in a week.

Comment: yes, so you can use set statement in the start and replace the dates .

Comment: No, according to the question as it stands, the date doesn't matter, so it's not necessary to set such a where clause. According to the question, only the time is important.

Comment: You ca use these queries .

FOR AM :

select * from table where timestamp(report_date) between '12:00:00' and '23:59:59'

FOR PM:

select * from table where timestamp(report_date) between '12:00:00' and '23:59:59'